# Solve matrix with parameters

Tags: matlab

I was trying to solve a matrix with parameters in matlab. So i defined `a` and `b` with `syms a b` and then my matrix `D = [-1 -2 2 1 -3; 1 1 a 1 2; 2 1 -1 b 3; 1 1 -1 1 2; -1 1 a -1-b 0]`

```
D =

[ -1, -2,  2,       1, -3]
[  1,  1,  a,       1,  2]
[  2,  1, -1,       b,  3]
[  1,  1, -1,       1,  2]
[ -1,  1,  a, - b - 1,  0]
```

When i do `rref(D)` it gives me the following:

```
>> rref(D)

ans =
[ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This actually useless for me, because i need the system solved with the resulting parameters in it.

Anyone an idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

well, it is pretty obvious that both `a` and `b` can be eliminated using `rref`,  since `a`  appears twice only in the 2nd col, and `b` appears twice only in the 4th col. For example,  (row2+row3)/(row5+row1) and bingo, no `a` and `b` ...